# Wikipediaのデータで辞書を作る

Tags: ライセンス

Wikipediaのデータで辞書（単語帳）を作ろうと考えています。
Wikipediaはよくフリーだと言われていますが、
ググってみるとWikipediaのデータで作った著作物は頒布義務があるということがわかりました。

Web上で辞書を頒布することは問題ないのですが、
頒布する際は頒布情報として
該当するWikipediaのページのURLを掲載するほかに
何か必要なものがあるでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia の記事[「Wikipedia:ウィキペディアを二次利用する」](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A3%E3%82%AD%E3%83%9A%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%A2%E3%82%92%E4%BA%8C%E6%AC%A1%E5%88%A9%E7%94%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)が非常に参考になります。

ライセンスに従って二次利用する場合、[クリエイティブ・コモンズ・ライセンス](https://creativecommons.jp/licenses/)についての理解が必要です。
[Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8) のページの一番下には、2018 年 9 月現在以下のように書かれています。

> テキストは[クリエイティブ・コモンズ 表示-継承ライセンス](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Text_of_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported_License)の下で利用可能です。追加の条件が適用される場合があります。詳細は[利用規約](https://foundation.wikimedia.org/wiki/Terms_of_Use/ja)を参照してください。

ここに書かれているように、Wikipedia のテキスト部分を利用するためには、クリエイティブ・コモンズ・ライセンスのうち[「表示 - 継承」という種類のライセンス](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.ja)を守る必要があります。

**大雑把に言うと**、Wikipedia のテキストを使うためには「**表示**：出典がどこで、それを作ったのは誰で、ライセンスは何で、変えた部分があればどこを変えたかを書く」ことと「**継承**：自分が作った部分を同じクリエイティブ・コモンズ・ライセンスで頒布する」ことが必要です。ただしこれは私の言葉で書き直した説明なので、必ず[元のライセンス文もご自身でご確認ください。](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A8%E3%82%A4%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%96%E3%83%BB%E3%82%B3%E3%83%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BA_%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA-%E7%B6%99%E6%89%BF_3.0_%E9%9D%9E%E7%A7%BB%E6%A4%8D)

このため今回の場合、元ページの URL だけでは不充分で、少なくともそれが Wikipedia からきたものであることと、クリエイティブ・コモンズ・ライセンスで配布されていたものであることを記載する必要があります。どのように書いたら良いかの例は、先にあげた記事[「Wikipedia:ウィキペディアを二次利用する」](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A3%E3%82%AD%E3%83%9A%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%A2%E3%82%92%E4%BA%8C%E6%AC%A1%E5%88%A9%E7%94%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)に書かれています。

更にテキストとは別に、画像や動画などに対してはそれぞれ個別にライセンスがあります。個別のメディアをクリックしていくと [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8) にあるそのメディア個別のページにたどり着きます。通常そのページに個別のライセンスが書かれており、それに従う必要があります。

---

※ 免責: 私は法律の専門家ではないので、この回答には不正確な点がある可能性があります。また、回答が古くなっている可能性もあります。必ずご自身でお確かめください。

Comment: 頒布義務というのが継承のところでURLの掲載だけでは表示が不十分ということですね。出典はページ上に書いてないのでURLの掲載でいいと思うんですけど作者とライセンスもページ上に書いてないのですが、どこかで確認する方法はあるのでしょうか。

Comment: 上のコメント訂正：頒布義務というのが継承のところに該当している。ただ、表示はURLの掲載だけでは表示が不十分ということですね。出典はページ上に書いてないのでURLの掲載でいいと思うんですけど作者とライセンスはページ上に書いてないのですが、どこかで確認する方法はあるのでしょうか。

Comment: @user30138 さん、[「Wikipedia:ウィキペディアを二次利用する」](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A3%E3%82%AD%E3%83%9A%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%A2%E3%82%92%E4%BA%8C%E6%AC%A1%E5%88%A9%E7%94%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)の「表示例」や[「Wikipedia:ウィキペディアを情報源とするサイト」](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A3%E3%82%AD%E3%83%9A%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%A2%E3%82%92%E6%83%85%E5%A0%B1%E6%BA%90%E3%81%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88)の「チェックポイント」が参考になるかと思います。